# Send Ical appointment with PHPMailer to office 365

Tags: php, outlook, office365, phpmailer, icalendar

I am using the latest version of PHPMailer Version 5.5

Below is the code I have written, I am trying to send an Ical appointment to our office 365 application within the company but it is not showing the RSVP buttons, it just adds the calendar appointment as an attachment.

I have tried setting it up using various tutorials I have found around the web with no luck, I think it depends what version of outlook you are using etc

When the email comes through I can open the attachment and add it to the calendar but it should automatically show the buttons to allow you to accept, tentative or decline the appointment.

I have actually generated the below $ical code using our own outlook application by exporting the .ics file and then set it up like below.

I believe it may be something to do with the headers but maybe someone that knows more about Outlook will be able to help?

Thanks in advance.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail = $this->setSMTPDetails($mail);

$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->setFrom('webdevelopment@chandcogroup.com', 'CH&CO Team');
$mail->addReplyTo('webdevelopment@chandcogroup.com', 'CH&CO Team');
$mail->addAddress($email,'Danny');
$mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar';

$mail->Subject = "WBBW day booking";
$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-version',"1.0");

$ical ="BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .="PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n";
$ical .="VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .="METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .="X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\r\n";
$ical .="BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
$ical .="TZID:GMT Standard Time\r\n";
$ical .="BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
$ical .="DTSTART:16011028T020000\r\n";
$ical .="RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10\r\n";
$ical .="TZOFFSETFROM:+0100\r\n";
$ical .="TZOFFSETTO:-0000\r\n";
$ical .="END:STANDARD\r\n";
$ical .="BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$ical .="DTSTART:16010325T010000\r\n";
$ical .="RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3\r\n";
$ical .="TZOFFSETFROM:-0000\r\n";
$ical .="TZOFFSETTO:+0100\r\n";
$ical .="END:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$ical .="END:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
$ical .="BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .="ATTENDEE;CN='Danny Hardy';RSVP=TRUE:mailto:webdevelopment@chandcogroup.com\r\n";
$ical .="CLASS:PUBLIC\r\n";
$ical .="CREATED:20181203T112515Z\r\n";
$ical .="DESCRIPTION: WBBW Day Booking\r\n";
$ical .="DTEND;TZID='GMT Standard Time':20181210T130000\r\n";
$ical .="DTSTAMP:20181203T111806Z\r\n";
$ical .="DTSTART;TZID='GMT Standard Time':20181210T120000\r\n";
$ical .="LAST-MODIFIED:20181203T112515Z\r\n";
$ical .="LOCATION:TVP\r\n";
$ical .="ORGANIZER;CN='James Gambrill':mailto:James.Gambrill@chandcogroup.com\r\n";
$ical .="PRIORITY:5\r\n";
$ical .="SEQUENCE:0\r\n";
$ical .="SUMMARY:Catch up Danny / James\r\n";
$ical .="TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n";
$ical .="UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000090974ADDF98AD401000000000000000
010000000016A2E1A28D2CB4F94035AA4D93C7DE9\r\n";
$ical .="X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'
xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-mic
rosoft-com:office:word' xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/
12/omml' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head>\n<meta name='Gener
ator' content='Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)'><style><!--\n/* Font D
efinitions */\n@font-face\n {font-family:'Cambria Math'\;\n panose-1:2 4 5
 3 5 4 6 3 2 4\;}\n@font-face\n {font-family:Calibri\;\n    panose-1:2 15 5 2
 2 2 4 3 2 4\;}\n/* Style Definitions */\np.MsoNormal\, li.MsoNormal\, div
.MsoNormal\n    {margin:0cm\;\n margin-bottom:.0001pt\;\n   font-size:11.0pt\;\
n   font-family:'Calibri'\,sans-serif\;\n   mso-fareast-language:EN-US\;}\na:l
ink\, span.MsoHyperlink\n   {mso-style-priority:99\;\n  color:#0563C1\;\n   tex
t-decoration:underline\;}\na:visited\, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\n  {mso-st
yle-priority:99\;\n color:#954F72\;\n   text-decoration:underline\;}\np.mson
ormal0\, li.msonormal0\, div.msonormal0\n   {mso-style-name:msonormal\;\n   ms
o-margin-top-alt:auto\;\n   margin-right:0cm\;\n    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto\
;\n margin-left:0cm\;\n font-size:11.0pt\;\n    font-family:'Calibri'\,sans-s
erif\;}\nspan.EmailStyle18\n    {mso-style-type:personal-compose\;\n    font-fam
ily:'Calibri'\,sans-serif\;\n   color:windowtext\;}\n.MsoChpDefault\n   {mso-s
tyle-type:export-only\;\n   font-size:10.0pt\;}\n@page WordSection1\n   {size:
612.0pt 792.0pt\;\n margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt\;}\ndiv.WordSection
1\n {page:WordSection1\;}\n--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n<o:shapede
faults v:ext='edit' spidmax='1026' />\n</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9
]><xml>\n<o:shapelayout v:ext='edit'>\n<o:idmap v:ext='edit' data='1' />\n
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang='EN-GB' link='#0563C1'
 vlink='#954F72'><div class='WordSection1'><p class='MsoNormal'><o:p>&nbsp
\;</o:p></p></div></body></html>\r\n";
$ical .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\r\n";
$ical .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\n";
$ical .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\n";
$ical .="X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\r\n";
$ical .="BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .="TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .="ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .="DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .="END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .="END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .="END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

$mail->Ical = "$ical";
$mail->Body = "This is the body";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body";

try {
 $mail->Send();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 mail("webdevelopment@chandcogroup.com", "Error with sending customer WBBW email on website", "$mail->ErrorInfo");
}
}
```

Comment: Please [read this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, that post does not help but thanks.

Comment: It does help in that it tells you that Outlook’s proprietary, undocumented, incompatible implementation is hard to work with.